# How does function template deduce types with const qualifier?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code with outputs. I have two questions.

1) foo1 < double, char* >(a,b); is not able to compile by gcc 4.1.2.
    It cannot instantiate it.

2) foo1(a,b); outputs AB, while foo(a,b) can output Ac. Is it because of the const qualifier?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename B>
class C {
public:
    void operator()(A a, B b) {
        std::cout << "AB" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename A>
class C<A, const char*> {
public:
    void operator()(A a, const char* b);
};

template<typename A>
void C<A, const char*>::operator()(A a, const char* b) {
    std::cout << "Ac" << std::endl;
}

template<typename A, typename B>
void foo(A a, B b) {
    C<A,B>()(a,b);
}

template<typename A, typename B>
class C1 {
public:
    void operator()(A a, const B b) {
        std::cout << "AB" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename A>
class C1<A, char*> {
public:
    void operator()(A a, const char* b);
};

template<typename A>
void C1<A, char*>::operator()(A a, const char* b) {
    std::cout << "Ac" << std::endl;
}

template<typename A, typename B>
void foo1(A a, B b) {
    C1<A,B>()(a,b);
}

int main() {
    double a = 0;
    const char *b;
    C<double, const char*>()(a,b);
    foo<double, const char*>(a,b);
    foo(a,b);

    C1<double, char*>()(a,b);
    //foo1<double, char*>(a,b); 
    foo1(a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Ac
Ac
Ac
Ac
AB
```

Comment: You say " foo1(a,b); is not able to compile by gcc 4.1.2. It cannot instantiate it. 2) foo1(a,b); outputs AB". The statements are inconsistent: is `foo(a,b)` not compilable, or does `foo(a,b) it output `AB`? Are you using multiple compiler versions? If so, clarify.

Comment: I don't understand the question, but keep in mind that `const char* p` is "non-const pointer to const char" while `const Type t` where `Type` is `const char*` is "const pointer to const char".

Comment: @BeeOnRope: I meant foo1<double, char*>(a,b). I changed my question.

Comment: @JamesRoot: I thought foo1(a,b) will take the specialized method of C1. But actually it calls that non-specialized one.

Comment: As far as your question goes, the into text I quoted above appears unchanged and still inconsistent.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, is <> a special thing in StackOverflow? It does not show anything w/o adding spaces around it. It works now.

Comment: It's a special thing in html markup based languages in general. I'm sure a quick google could solve your issue, here's some [random crap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150147/how-to-escape-the-angled-brackets-in-a-code-block) I found on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `foo1(a, b)` with `b` being a `const char*`, the type is deduced as `const char*`. The `const` applies to the type being pointed at, not the pointer itself. It can't drop the `const` because it is a vital part of the type. The specialization of `C1` is for `char*`. They don't match, and so the non-specialized version is used.

Also, in your specialized version of `C1`, your operator's signature isn't the same as it is in the non-specialized one.

```
//In C1<A, B>
void operator()(A a, const B b) //If B was char*, this could be char* const

//In C1<A, char*>
void operator()(A a, const char* b) //This is const char*
```